# PCL: Creating a real-time visualization from kinect point clouds

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

Im trying to follow  this tutorial: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php#openni-grabber but I'm not being able to complete it. The tutorial seems simple enough, but nothing seems to be working.

When I try to compile it I get the following error: point_cloud_geometry_handlers.h:48:29: fatal error: vtkSmartPointer.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

I've tried to find out what this vtkSmartPointer.h is about but with no luck, probably it has something to do with that ConstPtr type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using CMake to configure your project? It looks like you're forgetting to include the VTK library path, which is needed for vtkSmartPointer.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, thanks